# Animate Height Bottom to Top Instead of Top to Bottom

Tags: jquery, height, jquery-animate

How can I achieve height animation in reverse?

Instead of the typical animation starting from the top and working its way down, how can I have it start the animation from the bottom of the element and work its way up towards the top of the element?

The event is triggered by `a#link-1`, the animation takes place in `div#line-1`.

*This is my code: It doesn't appear to be working. :-/*

**HTML**

```
<div id="pageContainer">
    <div id="line-1"></div>
    <a id="link-1" title="" href="#">Link 1</a>
</div><!-- end #pageContainer -->
```

**CSS**

```
#pageContainer{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0px 200px 0px;
    min-height: 748px;
    height: 748px;
    background: url('../img/sprite.png') bottom center no-repeat;   
}
a#link-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 686px;
    left: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 76px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    z-index: 20;
}
div#line-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 340px;
    height: 687px;
    background: url('../img/sprite.png') 0px 0px no-repeat; 
}
```

**JS**

```
// Initially hide                      
$("div#line-1").hide();
// Activate Line 1
$('a#link-1').click(function() {
    $('div#line-1').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    height: 'toggle'
    }, 5000, function() {
// Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: Can we see your html structure and existing jQuery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `div` and your a tags have the same ID. They must have unique IDs.

```
$('a#line-1').click(function() {
    $('div#line-1').animate({
```

needs to be something like:

```
$('a#line-1').click(function() {
    $('div#unique_id').animate({
```

[**Example Fix**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9yJD/)

Answer (score 1):

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

animate bottom + 1.

You can also use negative values for `top` or `margin-top` to move upwards.

Comment: Great answer.. What he means is you position it with bottom: 0  and position absolute, rather than a top(margin), this way the element stays stuck to bottom and grows up.

Answer (score 0):

Animate as you would for top-to-bottom, but add `element.scrollTop = 99999;`

This will ensure that the bottom of the content is visible (unless for some reason it's 100,000 pixels tall) and the effect will be bottom-to-top animation.