# Start height animation from bottom instead of top

Tags: html, css

Like the title says I want to be able to start the height animation from the bottom instead of the top?? I understand this question has been asked a few times like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489606/animate-height-bottom-to-top-instead-of-top-to-bottom) but it doesn't answer my question and uses jQuery which I don't want to do.

I have created a simple jsFiddle of a [sliding box](https://jsfiddle.net/y0fbL4to/)

My code is as follows

```js
function addClass() {
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    box.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.box{
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
} 

.box.show{
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">

  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="addClass()">
  click me
</button>
```

my desired outcome is to have the box slide up from the bottom instead of the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```js
function addClass() {
 const box = document.querySelector('.box');
  box.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
    .container{
      height: 400px;
      width: 200px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .box{
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      top: 100%;
      background: black;
      transition: top 0.4s;
    }

    .box.show{
      top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="addClass()">
  click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to start your animation at the bottom of the page simply use

`position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;`

for your initial styling, this makes the position of the div or element go to x:0 y:0, setting `bottom: 0px` pushes it to the highest Y value you can place, forcing to the bottom of the page.